# SQL Server 2022 Express won't install. Is there an offline installer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Morning folks,

I've been attempting to install SQL Server Express 2022 for a class and I'm running into issues (due to restrictions on my network). Is there an offline installer as I can't get to the option select page to actually do the selection due to the network restrictions blocking the installer from downloading the next step.

I require the 2022 edition and not the 2019 version and am unable to reach the section which allows you to select your install method as it comes up with an error stating the below:

["A required file could not be downloaded. This could mean the version of the installer is no longer supported"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2hFu.png)

This is despite the installer being downloaded this morning.

I am unable to use Docker due to network policies restricting its use.

Comment: This has already been answered. The installer has an option to download the files locally. You can run it on a different machine that does have network access, save the files to a local folder then copy those files to the machine you want

Comment: Run the installer on a different network. If the network routers or firewalls don't allow you to download large files, they won't allow you to download a single 2GB ISO file either

Comment: link for specific 2022 offline version: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2213259&clcid=0x409

Answer (score -2):

Someone here describes here how you can install mssql without internet access.
https://optionkey.blogspot.com/2022/06/how-to-get-sql-express-offline-installer.html
It requires you to run this setup on a machine with access, it will give you the option to download all files.

Alternatively, you could install docker and use docker to run mssql. I really like the docker way because it does not pollute your system.
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Comment: That link is about a very specific component, not SQL Server itself

Comment: Unfortunately that does not cover Express which is the edition I require, also running a dockerised instance is not possible on my network (due to the restrictions placed)

Comment: I have changed my comment and linked a blog which is probably worth taking a look at @dan.robertson

Comment: `you could install docker and use docker to run mssql.` how will this bypass network restrictions that don't even allow a simple download?

Comment: Unfortunately that requires getting to a stage which I can not get to so this question is still unanswered

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe the firewall only blocks certain downloads and not docker. Also it is possible for the teacher to host a local docker registry if the network allows that.

Comment: @dan.robertson the question was answered in the past. The installer can download the installation files locally.

Comment: @Joost00719 in that case you should post a comment asking for clarification, not post answers that just might work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is for previous versions and does not work as per the updated question as I am unable to reach that section. Please allow this to be reopened.

Comment: @dan.robertson have you actually tried the installer? The `Download Media` option is even more prominent in 2022

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As stated in the reviewed question, when I run the installer, due to the restrictions on my network, it is unable to download a required file to setup the installer. This is why I am asking the question.

Comment: @dan.robertson and that option is in the installer itself. Run it on a different machine and click `Download Media`, then copy these files to the target machine. That's what offline installers are about. How else do you expect to download an "offline installer" if your network firewall prohibits downloading large files? If the firewall or router doesn't allow you to download large files, you have to do this outside that network. Even if you could find a 2GB ISO with the installer, how would you download it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There are known workarounds that we can apply on offline installers that do not work on the standard downloader hence why I am requesting information on it.